# A query for a latest version of data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view, datetime

MySQL.

Let there is a table with fields `startdate` and `kind`.

Actually in the real problem column named here `startdate` and `kind` are in a UNIQUE index, but the case if only `startdate` (not `kind`) is UNIQUE would be also interesting.

Let a date `d` is specified. I want to retrieve the data of given `kind` which corresponds to the latest `startdate` which is before `d`.

As far as I understand this cannot be efficiently done with views.

So, should it be done with a stored procedure? I am a novice in the topic of stored procedures. Your code would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy.

let @d be the date and @k be the kind :

```
select *
from table a
where 
  startdate = (select max(b.startdate) 
               from table b 
               where b.startdate < @d
               and b.kind = @k)
  and a.kind = @k
```

Comment: Your code does not restrict query only to fields with a specified `kind`. Please rewrite the query. I suppose that rewriting it in the most trivial way would make it inefficient. Probably we should use `LIMIT 1` instead?

Comment: I edited my question to make clear that we want only data of a given `kind`.

Comment: I've updated the query

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest the following:

## SUGGESTION #1 : Query as follows

```
SET @GivenKind = '...';
SET @GivenDate = d;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE kind=@GivenKind
AND startdate < @GivenDate
ORDER BY startdate DESC LIMIT 1;
```

## SUGGESTION #2 : Define a Good Index

In your question you said

> Actually in the real problem column named here startdate and kind are in a UNIQUE index, but the case if only startdate (not kind) is UNIQUE would be also interesting.

For my suggested query, you will need an index to support the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX kind_startdate_ndx (kind,startdate);
```

This will help the Query Optimizer immensely. Why?

- `kind` is a constant in the query
- `startdate` is in a range within the `kind`
- Order of the columns in the index matters

If this index does not exist, it could result in a range index/table scan or full index/table scan (if the `kind`'s cardinality is too low).

Having an index with `startdate,kind` will result in a range index scan. If you specify the `kind`.

Give it a Try !!!